# Как можно изменить код , чтобы задача решалась с использованием рекурсии?

Tags: python, рекурсия

Код для нахождения палиндромов из файла, состоящего из 100к слов. В конце выводится список найденных палиндромов. Как сделать тоже самое через рекурсию?

```
from dictionary import load

word_list = load("words.txt")
pali_list = []

for word in word_list:
    if len(word) > 1 and word == word[::-1]:
        pali_list.append(word)

print(*pali_list, sep='\n')

print(f"\nЧисло обнаруженных палиндромов = {len(pali_list)}.\n")
```

Comment: Если именно "тоже самое", т.е.  вы палиндром обнаруживаете для каждого слова в отдельности -  то причем тут рекурсия?  Если же вы хотите обнаруживать палиндром над целым текстом длиной "100к слов." -  то лучше эту затею оставить. Думаю, ресурсов вашего компьютера врят-ли хватит, особенно прииспользовании рекурсии.

Comment: Не понял вас, эта программа спокойно работает и выполняет свои функции. Единственное я бы здесь заменил список слов из словаря на множество, тогда эта программа выполняется вообще за пару секунд. Здесь можно создать рекурсивную функцию на проверку слова на палиндромность, если тру, то добавить его в список, но это в любом случае реализуется внутри цикла. Меня интересует возможно ли здесь заменить все циклы только рекурсией, чтобы выполнялась та же задача.

Comment: Все циклы - точно нельзя. Цикл чтения слов из файла если вы замените каким-то образом на рекурсию, то рекурсия должна будет выполниться 100К раз, а у Питона предел рекурсии где-то порядка 1К и это практически не лечится. Тут разве что только само определение палиндромности слова можно переделать на рекурсию в чисто учебных целях.